# Postgres - to_date('2016/99/99', 'YYYY/MM/DD') = '2024-06-23' ? How else do we verify valid dates?

Tags: postgresql, date

The unexpected thing about postgres is that a query like following is considered valid.

```
SELECT to_date('2016/99/99', 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS date
```

And you will get `date - 2024-06-23` from postgres even when it was clearly an invalid date.

The important requirement here is the ability to use different data formats in different queries.

Note :: Something like `'2016/99/99'::timestamp` or `'2016/99/99'::date` will not be able to support varying date formats. Just think the need of a function which takes the `date string` and a `format string` and creates a query. ( pls ignore things like sql escaping etc for now)

```
function(dateString, formatString) {
  return "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE created_at = to_date('" + dateString + ", '" + formatString + ')";
}
```

Now, how are we supposed to ensure the date (for dates in custom formats) validity in queries ?

Comment: At some point it was discussed to add a `to_date_exact()` function or something similar but unfortunately that hasn't happened yet. The main concern if I recall correctly was how to deal with users coming from Oracle that expect `to_date()` to fail without changing the semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could format the result back with the input format and compare both:

```
with to_check (input, format) as (
  values 
    ('2016/99/99', 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 
    ('88-88-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
    ('2016-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
)
select input, to_char(to_date(input, format), format) = input as is_valid
from to_check;
```

returns:

```
input      | is_valid
-----------+---------
2016/99/99 | false   
88-88-2019 | false   
2016-01-01 | true
```

---

I just saw Eugene's last comment to his answer. That caveat of course applies for this solution as well. `2016/9/9` will fail the above test.

Comment: this will be a great help in writing a `to_safe_date` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another casting method:

```
psql (9.5.4)

el=# SELECT to_date('2016/99/99', 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS date;
    date
------------
2024-06-23
(1 row)

el=# SELECT '2016/99/99'::timestamp;
ERROR:  value of  date/time out of range: "2016/99/99"
ROW 1: SELECT '2016/99/99'::timestamp;
             ^
HINT:  Perhaps, you need to change setting "datestyle".
el=# SELECT '2016/9/9'::timestamp;
   timestamp
---------------------
2016-09-09 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: is there any way to support varying data formats and relying on postgres to check the validity.

Comment: You may look at `datestyle` settings. 
But as a common rule better to filter data before it gets to Database. Otherwise you can get an SQL Injection.

Comment: `SELECT to_char(to_date('2016/09/09', 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY/MM/DD') = '2016/09/09';` gives you `True`. 
But `SELECT to_char(to_date('2016/99/99', 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY/MM/DD') = '2016/99/99';` gives you `False`. But pay attention to the date format, `2016/9/9` will also give you `False` because it will be `2016/09/09`.

Comment: that will not be an issue as something like '2016/9/9' needs to be treated as invalid.